# How do I pass kilogram, gram to a kilogram converter and obtain the result in grams

Tags: java, jscience

How do I pass kilogram, gram to a kilogram converter and obtain the result in grams
(e.g. 5 kg 500 grams = 5500 grams)

How to do this using javax.measure.* Refer over [here](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/package-summary.html)

**Note**: I need the solution only based on the above packages and not some generic solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a rather cumbersome API, but something like this?

```
int grams = Measure.valueOf(5, SI.KILOGRAM).intValue(SI.GRAM) + 
            Measure.valueOf(500, SI.GRAM).intValue(SI.GRAM);
```

There's probably a more formal method for arithmetic on `Measure` values, but I can't find it.